# How to specify custom registry for yarn upgrade similar to yarn install?

Tags: html, user-interface, hadoop-yarn, package.json

I am running into an issue where before performing yarn install I am creating a .yarnrc file and yarn install is using the same file to install all dependencies. Once this is done I am calling upgrade for one of my package but this is failing and it is not taking the above created file for upgrading of dependencies.
Any idea how this can be achieved?